# MethodDecorator & ClassDecorator types have no intersection. Why is it still a useful type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I wrote a decorator in TypeScript that can be used as either a MethodDecorator or ClassDecorator. I have accepted that TypeScript never intended me to do this, and that is why I need to type it in such a funky way (see below).

There is still one thing that is bothering me. MethodDecorator & ClassDecorator have no intersection as far as I can tell. Yet, when I remove that line, TypeScript no longer throws a compilation error when I decorate a property. (I want it to throw compilation errors when I decorate something that is not a class or method.)

What is TypeScript doing that causes a type with no intersection to still be useful?

I am using es2019 with experimentalDecorators, emitDecoratorMetadata, and sourceMap.

```
export default function Trace<A extends unknown[], C>():
  | (MethodDecorator & ClassDecorator)
  | ((
      target: Record<string | symbol, any>,
      propertyKey?: string | symbol,
      descriptor?: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: A) => C>,
    ) => void) {
  return function (
    target: new (...args: A) => C,
    propertyKey?: string | symbol,
    descriptor?: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: A) => C>,
  ):
    | void
    | (new (...args: A) => C)
    | TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: A) => C> {
    const applyWrap = (
      methodName: string | symbol,
      originalMethod: (...args: A) => C,
    ): ((...args: A) => C) => {
      const wrappedMethod: (...args: A) => C = originalMethod;
      return function (...args: A): C {
        return wrappedMethod?.apply(this, args);
      };
    };

    if (typeof propertyKey === 'undefined') {
      // Decorator is applied to all methods of a class
      Reflect.ownKeys(target?.prototype)?.forEach(
        (methodName: string | symbol): void => {
          const originalMethod: (...args: A) => C =
            target?.prototype[methodName];
          if (typeof originalMethod === 'function') {
            target.prototype[methodName] = applyWrap(
              methodName,
              originalMethod,
            );
          }
        },
      );
      return target;
    } else if (descriptor) {
      // Decorator is applied to a method
      const originalMethod: (...args: A) => C = descriptor?.value;
      if (typeof originalMethod === 'function') {
        descriptor.value = applyWrap(propertyKey, originalMethod);
      }
      return descriptor;
    }
    return;
  };
}
```

Comment: Is this a [mre]? If I paste this into my own IDE I get a lot of errors, both [with](https://tsplay.dev/Wk8Z0w) and [without](https://tsplay.dev/Nn8ZaW) targeting legacy decorators (from now on, whenever someone mentions "decorators" in TS, they really should say whether they're talking about *legacy* TS decorators, or [JS decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#decorators), because they're quite different, and as time goes on nobody's going to bother supporting the legacy ones).  So it's not reproducible.  (more)

Comment: (continued) And I doubt it's minimal either; do you need jest and dd-trace dependencies to demonstrate the issue which has to do presumably with intersections or something and not the actual functionality?  ... Could you [edit] the code in the question to be both minimal and easily reproducible?  That will help you get useful engagement.  Good luck!

Comment: It's a little confusing but when you intersect two types, A and B, it's not actually A ∩ B but more similar to A ∪ B.

Comment:  No, it's definitely A ∩ B. You're thinking of "sets of properties" which is not fruitful.  You should be thinking of "sets of values assignable to the type".  The available properties are contravariant in the object types, so if you think of the key names you'll be looking at it upside down.

Comment: Sorry @jcalz, I replaced my code with a minimal reproducible example. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: I'm not understanding the code example; I see [this in my IDE](https://tsplay.dev/mM79kw): one huge error.  Is that what you're asking about? If not, please resolve it or tell me how to reproduce what you're seeing.  If so, what specifically are you asking?

Comment: There is no error for me, and that may be about the options I have in my tsconfig . I am using es2019 with experimentalDecorators, emitDecoratorMetadata, and sourceMap. Should I also include the contents of my tsconfig too, since it looks like it is necessary for the minimal reproducible example?

Comment: It couldn't hurt... but you could probably play around with [this example](https://tsplay.dev/mxxdxm)'s config to see which compiler options are relevant. But it's still massively more code than needed for a [mre]. If the question is "what does this intersection mean" then all you need is a `declare`d value of the intersection type to ask about it. And the answer is shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/wQ0nJW): intersections of functions do overlap and are equivalent to [overloads](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). Should I post an answer?